# Reducing the acceleration of uniform circular motion in 2d space

Tags: java, physics, game-engine, game-physics

I have a rotating a wheel image based on WHEEL OF FORTUNE game. I am using the uniform circular rotation formula.

Angular Velocity V = 2*Pi / T(time taken for the whole spin)

Speed of rotation  S = v * r(radius of the wheel)

If I increase the time interval T in V(Angular velocity), the wheel slows down.

Can I get your valuable idea or solution to decrease the time T regularly to get a smooth animation of about 10-15 seconds to stop the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you can get a decent result by assuming a constant rate of energy loss. Rotation energy is given by *E = 1/2 * I * w<sup>2</sup>*, where *w* is the angular velocity (it should really be a Greek omega), and *I* (a capital i) is the moment of inertia, which is constant for a given object and axis of rotation. We get *w = sqrt(2 * E / I)*, so try letting *E* start out at some suitable value and decrease linearly towards 0, and use the above formula to compute the angular velocity.